# Angular 2 Can't get ngModel to work right with checkbox

Tags: angular

I have an edit form where the data comes from a database with an array of role objects that consists of a name and a selected property. I have a checkbox for each role object in the array. When the form loads, the checkbox is not checked even though looking at the object the selected property is true. If I check a checkbox the role.selected value in the label below changes so I'm not sure why the checkbox won't be checked when the form first loads. I've tried adding `[value]="role.selected"` and `[checked]="role.selected"` and that doesn't change anything. Any help is greatly appreciated. I'm sure it's something simple that I can't see after looking at it for hours.

```
<div class="checkbox" *ngFor="let role of userToEdit.allRoles">
     <label><input type="checkbox" name="role" [(ngModel)]="role.selected" >{{role.name}}, {{role.selected}}</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All your inputs should have a distinct name.

```
<div class="checkbox" *ngFor="let role of roles; let i = index">
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="role_{{ i }}" [(ngModel)]="role.selected" >{{role.name}}, {{role.selected}}</label>
</div>
```

[Working demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/mxN7KVkoCgr3uzdI5Xek?p=preview).